# Permanently installing iOS apps on Apple Silicon macs with System Integrity Protection disabled?

Tags: applications, install, ios-appstore, apple-silicon

While it's normally possible to install iOS apps from the App Store and run them on an Apple Silicon mac, Apple has made it so that systems with System Integrity Protection disabled aren't allowed to do this. This is because the system's functionality for decrypting apps with FairPlay DRM is disabled when SIP is off, and apps from the App Store have this DRM.

It's also possible to install decrypted iOS apps on an Apple Silicon mac regardless of whether SIP is enabled. However these apps need to be signed and provisioned, meaning they expire after 7 days, or after at most a year with a paid developer account.

I'd like to find a method to install and run iOS apps on a mac without SIP and with no expiration. Preferably this method would allow running FairPlay encrypted apps that can be obtained without needing a jailbroken iOS device or re-enabling SIP.

Since such a method would be used on a mac without SIP, that means that the full range of hackery possible with those security features turned off is on the table! Perhaps there's a way to patch running system processes to bypass these restrictions? (One person seems to have gotten pretty far with this, [as mentioned here](https://jhftss.github.io/Install-decrypted-IPA-on-M1-Mac/) in a blog post.) Something simpler and less hacky would be even better.